# SSH into a guest VM

Tags: networking, 13.04, virtualbox, ssh

I have a CentOS as a guest VM. My host machine is 13.04. The CentOS can see the web but I cannot ssh into that VM.

My guest machine is CentOS 6.4 running in VirtualBox. From the VM window, I can update via yum and even browse on `lynx`. It reports an internal IP of 10.0.2.15. However I cannot ssh from my host machine into this one. To double check, I've even turned off iptables.

Did I miss any steps? How might I be able to SSH into the guest from host?

VirtualBox Session Info 
[image]

ifconfig of Guest (CentOS) 
[image]

VirturalBox Network
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the network interface from nat to bridged or host only.
see http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

Comment: Not necessary, when on NAT, you access it via 127.0.0.1, but when bridged, what do you access it on? thats my issue

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to run NAT? The NAT is hiding your VM. Think of NAT in firewall terms, unless you open a hole in your firewall anything initiated from outside the firewall is denied.

If you switch to bridged adapter then you will be able to reach your VM from "outside" your system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the settings of the VM network from NAT to Bridged Adaptor for you to SSH to your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your openssh-daemon is running. From root level `service sshd status`.